# Is there a way to call a method which will get defined in inherited class?

Tags: c++, oop, functional-programming

I've made this fragment of code:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector : public vector<T> {
    static constexpr auto identity   = [](T x) {return x;};
    static constexpr auto accept_all = [](T x) {return true;};
    static constexpr auto sum        = [](T x, T y) {return x+y;};
public:
    Vector<T>& map(T (*f)(T x) = identity) {
        for(int i=0; i < this->size(); i++)
            (*this)[i] = f((*this)[i]);

        return *this;
    }
    Vector<T>& filter(bool (*acceptable)(T x) = accept_all) {
        for(int i=0; i < this->size(); i++)
            if(not acceptable((*this)[i]))
                this->erase(this->begin() + i);

        return *this;
    }
    T fold(T (*f)(T x, T y) = sum) {
        T result = (*this)[0];
        for(int i=1; i < this->size(); i++)
            result = f(result, (*this)[i]);

        return result;
    }
};
```

It extends the `vector` class with functional methods `map`, `filter`, `fold`. Notice how `vector` can be replaced with a `deque` and it's still going to work because these classes share a common interface. In fact, anything that implements the `operator[]`, `size()` and `erase()` methods could be used instead. I'd like to generalize this with inheritance.

Let's say there exists such a class `FunctionalMethods` that can be inherited from by any class which supports the `operator[]`, `size()`, `erase()` methods, and which will implement the previously mentioned functionality.

If such a class existed, writing

```
template <typename T>
class Vector : public vector<T>, public FunctionalMethods {};
```

Exactly as is would create exactly the same class as in the first example.

**For such a class to exist, there needs to be a way to call methods which will get defined in another inherited class. Can it somehow be done?**

I know that I can generalize this example by using templates:

```
template <template<class> class Container, class T>
class Functional : public Container<T> {
    ...
};
```

where the `Functional` class has exactly the same implementation as the previous `Vector` class, but every occurrence of `Vector<T>` is replaced with `Container<T>`. However, this method yields an ugly syntax (for example, `Functional<vector, int>` has to be used instead of `Vector<int>`). It's also less general than the previously mentioned inheritance method because it does not allow splitting a class into individual modules, which can be reused.

Comment: OOP may not be the best way to handle this. Consider the alternative used by the standard library: Free functions like [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), and [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), which do indeed have the flexibility to work with any container that exposes an appropriate interface.

Comment: The pattern for this is called CRTP. `template<typename D> struct FunctionalMethods { D& map(T(*f)(D::value_type x)) { D& self = static_cast<D&>(*this); for(int i=0; i < self.size(); i++) { self[i] = f(self[i]); } return self; } };`. And then you say `template<typename T> struct Vector : std::vector<T>, FunctionalMethods<Vector<T>> { ... };` But @NathanPierson's suggestion is probably better.